# Why did only Ichigo inherited the Shinigami, Quincy and Hollow powers, not his siblings?

Tags: bleach

There may be spoilers from Bleach: Thousand Year Blood War.

In Bleach, we see that Ichigo has the powers of a Shinigami (Soul Reaper), a Hollow, a Quincy, and a Fullbringer, where the first three of these were inherited. Due to his mother, Masaki, being a Quincy, who also absorbed a Hollow, and his father, Isshin (Shinigami) sealing the hollow inside Masaki.

Then why were these inherited by only Ichigo?

It could've stayed with Masaki or would've been transferred to his siblings as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some of this is speculation, but it does help make sense of things.

1. Ichigo was the firstborn. It's likely he got the lion's share of any inherited abilities. We already know he has the most spiritual pressure of any of his family. That doesn't mean he got all the powers. Karin can see spirits and Yuzu can sense them.
2. Ichigo was directly converted into a Soul Reaper by Rukia. That clearly awakened something within him. It's possible Karin and Yuzu could awaken additional powers if they underwent that same process.
3. Ichigo continues to train and evolve. That training has, in turn, evolved the people around him (like Orihime). Ichigo has fought to keep his family out of the battles that would have made them stronger.

Comment: This does make sense, but what about the hollow?

Comment: The hollow falls into category #1: Ichigo inherited most of that power.

Comment: I think you could make a point that Ichigo's dad is still anchoring the hollow inside of Yuzu and Karin in the same way he did for Masaki. I think that may be an interesting arc if it was fully fleshed out.